# Alternative to Selenium scripts to download web data

Tags: web-scraping, automation, selenium-ide, build-automation, browser-automation

I have to extract web data every day,to automate it I am using selenium recording script if i run recording script  it will automatically download data based on my recording.Now i want alternative to do this task which has to do changes the dates and a few other changes in the website, then clicks the download button.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please present what you have tried, what's worked, what hasn't to expect an answer.

Comment: its just selenium IDE Recording..no coding at all.

Answer (score 0):

@raju your question is very generic.Please make it more precise next time.

As per my understanding search for parameterization in selenium ide should help you. These are very basic case. Try with this at least something. Still you face some issue post the query with complete error log. We will be more than happy to help you.